# C, linked data structures and double pointer behavior

Tags: c++, c, pointers

This question is regarding a deletion function of a singly linked list, where a value is searched for and removed. Please consider the following code:

```
void delete(node **a, int d)
{
    node *temp = *a;
    node *b = NULL;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data == d)
        {
            node *c = temp;
            if(b == NULL)
            {
                *a = temp->next;
            }
            else
            {
                b->next = temp->next;
                temp = b;
            }
            free(c);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            b = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the pointer variable `temp` that points to the value contained in the double pointer `a`, behaves predictably except for when the value to be deleted, which is `d` is the first element of the linked list. Here, if I simply write `temp = temp->next` instead of `*a = temp->next`, and remove the lines `node *c = temp` and `free(c)` so that temp is not affected in any way, it turns out that the node pointer outside of the function does not change and no deletion occurs. This prompts me to wonder why in other cases `temp` is able to change `*a`, but not in the aforementioned instance. My thoughts are that `*a` won't change unless the pointer pointing to it is changed by `temp->next` instead of just `temp`. However, this problem only shows up when structs are involved as function parameters.

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Can you explain the issue in a single line? It is very difficult to comprehend the issue after reading the paragraph ( I did read it thrice now).

Comment: What is the question?  I don't see any sentence which ends by question mark.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't able to convey properly. Why will this code not work if I simply write simply write temp = temp->next instead of *a = temp->next in the above code

Comment: @AminIqbal Because *a and temp are different. temp is a copy of *a. It is like expecting a to be 2 after `a=1; b=a; b=2;`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya but the else case does change the value of *a. when i assign temp = b, *a is changed.

Comment: @AminIqbal I am sure *a won't change after changing temp even in the else part. You can try this to verify add the line `printf("*a = %p, temp = %p\n", *a, temp);` before and after the modification of temp and you will see the difference.

Comment: The code works and deletion does occur if the value to the deleted is not the first element in the linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here, if I simply write temp = temp->next instead of *a = temp->next, and remove the lines node *c = temp and free(c) so that temp is not affected in any way, it turns out that the node pointer outside of the function does not change and no deletion occurs.

`*a = temp->next` and `temp = temp->next`

are different.

`temp = temp->next` means that now temp stores the address of next node
 but the `head` pointer still points to first node cause you haven't changed it.

But `*a = temp->next`

here `*a` store address of head pointer(i.e. starting node). That means changing `*a` will change head pointer.

Comment: but if you consider the case where b is not NULL, b->next = temp->next and then temp = b clearly affects *a as deletion does indeed take place.

Comment: Yes because you are not changing temp, you are changing temp->next which means you are modifying node's next pointer directly and hence *a

Comment: So what is the difference between temp and temp->next? they are both pointer nodes temp points to *a and temp->next points to (*a)->next. Why won't changing temp work?

Comment: In reality temp does not point anywhere. It only stores value at *a(i.e. head pointer's address). When you do this temp=temp->next means now temp stores next node's address but *a will remain same because temp only now stores new address and does not modify anything else other than itself.

Comment: I finally understand. Thank you.

Comment: Right, and temp and *a are different. temp is another variable so midifying temp wont change *a. but modifying temp->next means now you are changing *a->next but not temp itself

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you pass a `node **`, presumably to make it possible modify a pointer outside the function, but then you modify it even if the value that is to be deleted isn't at the head.

The solution is to ditch `temp`, and work with the abstraction that is `a` (i.e. the link you keep track off, and need to modify). Then you don't need `b` and your code is much simpler:

```
void delete(node **a, int d) {
  if (!a)
    return;

  while(*a != NULL) {
    if((*a)->data == d) {
      node *c = *a;
      *a = c->next;
      free(c);
      break;
    }
    else {
       a = &((*a)->next); // When you pass to the next node, you need to
                          // modify the link in the current node on removal
    }
  }
}
```